# Restfull cache error

Tags: caching, 8

I have a custom get resource API. The resource working fine. Whenever I clear cache, resource doesn't work and show error.

> The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata,
>   but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering
>   content too early.

I follow some topic and edit code like this

```
$build = [
  '#cache' => [
    'max-age' => 86400,
    'contexts' => [
      'url.query_args',
    ],
    'tags' => [
      'http_response'
    ],
  ],
];
$res = new ResourceResponse($response, 200);
$res->addCacheableDependency($build);
return $res;
```

or

```
$res = new ResourceResponse($response, 200);
$res->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheTags(['http_response']);
return $res;
```

but still error. Please help!

**Update**

After debug. I fixed $response.

```
$response = [
  'total' = '10',
  'comment' = 'comment'
];
```

And comment some line code.

```
$field_definition = $node->getFieldDefinition('field_event_comments');
$mode = $field_definition->getSetting('default_mode');

$storage_comment = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('comment');

$comments = $storage_comment->loadThread($node, 'field_event_comments', $mode);
```

**Update 2**
Create new simple rest resource with code:

```
$comment = Comment::load(387);// comment id exited
return new ResourceResponse('data', 200);
```

Error don't show. When uncomment error show again.

Comment: the problem is not the code you show, look in the rest of the controller code for early rendering, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php/class/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber/8.3.x or show an example of how you build the response data

Comment: After you get $comments, how to you process them for $response?

Comment: I fixed response.

Comment: There is nothing obvious in your code, which could be considered as early rendering. But this is sometimes hard to tell. In this case it could be the access checks of database queries in CommentStorage::loadThread() , see https://www.drupal.org/node/2638686

Comment: though testing loadThread() in one of my resource controllers didn't trigger the exception, are you sure you have no other code that does early rendering?

Comment: I process some features. I try comment step by step features. And find problem at load comment.

Comment: @4k4 Seem problem with method comment load. Whenever I clear cache, error show again.